# Given a permutation function, find the number of repetition required to get the original input

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Input: an array of character, and a permutation function P. The function P shuffles the input in some deterministic way. For example, if P is (push right)

> 1234 -> P -> 4123 -> P -> 3412 -> P -> 2341 -> 1234

In the above example, apply P **four** times to an input would give you an input.
P can be an identity mapping, that is, the require repetition is one

> 1234 -> P -> 1234

P can be viewed as some mapping function that eventually shuffles the input, and **the output of P needs to be a permutation of the original input**. P can be complicated, say swap odds and even; next, swap first and last, and so on.

You job is to write a function, say,

```
public static char[] P(char[] arr) {...} # the content is unknown
public static int getNumRequired(char[] arr) {
  // your code here
}
```

Apparently, there's a brute-force solution -- by creating a while loop, we count # of loops, and then break the loop when the condition is met. And the question here is: "can we do better than the brute-force?"

I was told that there's an efficient way (or better way) to figure the *number of repetition required* to get the original input.

Comment: This will be dependent on the kind of permuation function you have. If these are cryptographic hash functions, well, that will be hard. It is also important in what kind of setup you want do do this? One-time inverse? Multiple-time reverse (many different input values)? In the latter case, the technique of [Rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) may be appropriate. These may work for you, even if these are only space/time-tradeoffs (no change in complexity!)

Comment: Is it assumed that the permutation applied by the function does not depend on the specific values in the input?

Comment: Yes, the function P does NOT depend on the values of input. P is given and won't change w.r.t inputs. Our goal is to figure out # of repetition required if a P and arr are provided.

Answer (score 3):

**Basic Idea:** Consider the movement of each number in the list of permutations. It will form a cycle with a particular length. The cycle formed by each number could be a cycle of different length in the range `0 - (n-1)`. Then the whole permutation will repeat when all cycles meet, which will be the same as the LCM (Least Common Multiple) of the cycle-lengths.

In an algorithmic way:

1. For each number, find the number of permutations before which you get to the same number. In the given example, for `1` it is: `1->4->3->2->1`, so the number of permutations is `4`.
2. Get the LCM (Least Common Multiple) of all of the above permutations. This will be the number you seek.

In the above example:

```
1->4->3->2->1 ==> 4
2->1->4->3->2 ==> 4
3->2->1->4->3 ==> 4
4->3->2->1->4 ==> 4
and
LCM(4, 4, 4, 4) = 4
```

The brute force may take up to `O(n!)` complexity. The above will have at most a run of `O(n)` per digit and hence the overall complexity is `O(n^2) + <complexity of getting LCM>`.

**Note:** I believe the complexity of getting the LCM of two numbers is the same as getting the GCD of two numbers. I will update the result once I figure out the computation.

**Complexity of computing LCM of N numbers**:
We have, for say 4 numbers a, b, c, d:

```
LCM(a, b, c, d) = a*b*c*d / GCD(abc, abd, acd, bcd)
```

and

```
GCD (abc, abd, acd, bcd) = GCD(abc, GCD(abd, GCD(acd, bcd)))
```

Also `GCD(x,y)` can be computed in `O(log(x) + log(y))` time.

In the worst case, we will need to compute `LCM(1, 2, ..., n-1, n)`. This will lead to computation of `GCD(n!/1, GCD(n!/2, GCD(n!/3, ..., GCD(n!/(n-1), n!/n))))`. This will have a complexity of `O(log(n!/1), log(n!/2) + ... + log(n!/n))` which is the same as `O((n-1) * log(n!))` or `O(n^2 * log(n))`

Hence overall time complexity of the above approach is `O(n^2 * log(n))`.

Comment: It will move all four numbers. The idea above is to consider each number separately. The numbers may have different lengths for 'cycles' and when all cycles meet, the whole permutation repeats.

Comment: Added a note explaining the same.